# Как сделать чтоб AsynTask работали паралельно?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение в нём используется `AsyncTask` в его методе `doBack`.. цикл for из 10000 итераций.Так же ещё пару `Asynctask`-ов используется.Я запускаю ещё 1 таск но он попадает в ожидание.Как избежать этого????хочу чтоб он не ждал других а начал работать при методе `execute`

Comment: уже не первый ваш вопрос про асинктаски, если и дальше будет много работы с многопоточностью, советую глянуть в сторону RxJava. Сначала будет больно, но потом без неё жить не сможете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запускайте Ваши таски методом [`executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...))
По умолчанию (при запуске методом `execute(params)`) все `AsyncTask` выполняются по очереди в одном потоке.